# C++ disallow command prompt from displaying

Tags: c++, shell, command-prompt

Is there any thing I can do to make sure that the shell/command prompt does not show up when I run my C++ program, it is meant to be a background program? While it isn't a huge deal if it displays because it quickly closes, I would prefer it doesn't display at all. Program will run on windows xp/vista/7 OS

Comment: Which IDE are you using? There's a setting for that. Otherwise, you can use `ShowWindow (GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);` at the beginning to make it come up, flash, and be hidden the entire time if you use the Windows API.

Comment: I'm using Notepad++ to write the code and creating the exe from the command prompt, i'm not using something like eclipse, as for ShowWindow...using that makes the command prompt flash and hide, but its more of a pet peeve to make it not display at all even upon execution, the program itself just takes clickable sip links from browsers and opens up a softphone to dial, once or twice is not a big deal, but dialing several hundred numbers a day makes it quite annoying to see the command prompt over and over again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure your compiler or linker to mark your program as a GUI application.

Windows recognizes two main types of programs: GUI and console. If the EXE header is marked as a console program, then the OS creates a console window prior to executing it. Otherwise, it doesn't. This isn't something you can control at run time; you need to set it at link time. (You can call `ShowWindow(GetConsoelWindow(), SW_HIDE)` to try to control it at run time, but that doesn't prevent the window from flickering on and then off again. Plus, if your program is sharing the console with another program, like cmd.exe, then you'll have just hidden the user's command-prompt window!) Even if your program doesn't have any actual GUI, that's still the mode you need to avoid having a console window created for you.

If you're starting a new project in Visual Studio, select the "Win32 Console Application" option. If you already have a project, then in your project's configuration properties, find the "Subsystem" setting of the "Linker/System" section and set it to "Console." That makes the linker use the `/subsystem:console` option. If you're using Mingw, use the `-Wl,--subsystem,windows` option.

Comment: Is there a reason you would do this instead of simply creating a service application?

Comment: Rob's answer is a lot easier and I believe it fits your needs

Comment: Maybe a service wouldn't have the right permissions, @EdS. Maybe the program needs to run on demand instead of at system startup.

Comment: Yeah I agree.  I missed the "program will be short lived" bit the first time I read it, my mind went straight to "service".

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like you want to create a Windows service, not a command line utility.  This is why services exist.  Long running background tasks that require no user interaction.  [A simple example here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16488/A-Windows-Service-Application).

Comment: The program in question "quickly closes"; doesn't seem like a long-running background task to me.